# python easy_install fails with SSL certificate error for all packages

Tags: python, django, ssl, easy-install, pypi

**Goal:** I'm on RedHat 5 and trying to install the latest python and django for a web app.

I successfully altinstalled python27 and easy_install, and wget with openssl.

**Problem:** However now that I try to get anything from pypi.python.org I get the following error:

```
$ sudo easy_install --verbose django
Searching for django
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'django' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for django
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('django')
```

I tried looking up the certificate of pypi.python.org with openssl s_client -showcert -connect but don't know what to do with it, where to store it. Not much info on google, need expert help.

Thank you!

edit: I meant wget* with openssl.

```
$ wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.15.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf wget-1.15.tar.gz
$ cd wget-1.15
$ ./configure --with-ssl=openssl
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

I can't get wget to pull the page either:

```
$ wget https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
--2014-01-21 11:18:45--  https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
Resolving pypi.python.org (pypi.python.org)... 199.27.73.185, 199.27.74.184
Connecting to pypi.python.org (pypi.python.org)|199.27.73.185|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify pypi.python.org's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to pypi.python.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Comment: Run this command, it seems your CA certs are not updated: `curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` and then try again.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Spot on.. thanks for that.  You should submit that as an answer, its likely everyone's struggle...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

your curl cert is too old try to download new curl cert:

```
sudo wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -O /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, per one of the other posts, the `/etc/pki/tls/certs` directory need not exist beforehand as it's a hard coded location that will be searched by setuptools.

Comment: Do `mkdir -p /etc/pki/tls/certs` first if `/etc/pki/tls/certs` does not exist.

Answer (score 9):

I found this page after looking for a solution to this problem. In case someone else has similar problem, the solution I found is:

At the start of the `setuptools/ssl_support.py` file (which is used by easy_install, and is inside the egg file: `./lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.5.1-py2.7.egg`), the certificate bundles files are hard-coded in `cert_paths` variable:

```
cert_paths = """
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
/usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
/usr/local/share/certs/ca-root.crt
...etc..
"""
```

`easy_install` will use the first file that exists from this list, as it calls `find_ca_bundle`. If certificates in this cert bundle file are out of date, then easy_install will fail with this SSL error. So need to either update the certificate file or change the `cert_paths` in this `ssl_support.py` file, to point to a local up-to-date certs bundle file.

Comment: [Still exists in the `setuptools` code base in 2020](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/dabd73137f97145cc95c114937c95b217ac76876/setuptools/ssl_support.py#L21-L30)

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this problem in a specific environment: Mac OS X with macports, installing packages in user's local path. The solution was to install the certificates from curl:

```
port install curl-ca-bundle
```

Btw, until you don't have the ceritificates, most of the `port`, `easy_install` and `pip` commands will fail because the ssl error.

Answer (score -3):

Try installing `pip` to do python package installation instead.

You can find the documentation to quick install it and use it [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/). It's generally a lot better than `easy_install`.

It also uses SSL by default, and with Requests' certificate stack (derived from mozilla).

You can also find a lot of information on working with python packages in general on the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: This is circular advice. The pip sites directs me to install ez_setup.py which is easy_install. I need to solve this certificate error. It seems to plague more than just this.

Comment: Hi there, the `get-pip.py` bootstrap file should no longer require `ez_setup.py` :) It will install both `pip` and `setuptools` for you.

The specific reason I suggest pip is that it should come with its own CA cert stack for verifying the connection.

Comment: i can download get-pip.py with no-check-certificate, but once I run it, it gives me certificate errors trying to install setuptools and pip.

Comment: I'm now thinking that the reason that `wget` can't securely connect to pypi would also be the reason anything else (like `pip` and `easy_install`) cannot either. Certainly PyPI's Cert works just fine for many many other devices I use over SSL/TLS.

Have you tried with a latest build of OpenSSL? I suspect RedHat 5's would be getting quite old.

Comment: Yeah maybe old openssl, I moved hosts to a debian wheezy and everything installed perfectly the first time. Debain 1, RedHat 0

Comment: @Ivo, this worked for me. All of my wget statements needed a --no-check-certificate in order to work, but subsequent pip install commands on packages that are behind https worked fine.

Comment: There are some situations were you must use easy_install.  pip is great, but it's not the solution to this problem.