# Windows 8.1, Python(x,y) 2.7.6.0: "python easy_install" fails with SSL certificate error

Tags: python, windows, ssl, easy-install, pypi

On Windows 8.1, with Python(x,y) 2.7.6.0: "python easy_install" fails with SSL certificate error:

```
*******************************
Searching for behave
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/behave/
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
easy_install : Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/behave/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL 
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'behave' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL 
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for behave
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('behave')
*******************************
```

Obviously the SSL connection is broken. Of course normal Internet access by browser works fine, plus in-house Windows network.

By Internet research I did not find any clue, e.g. some other users got the same error recently: 
[python easy_install fails with SSL certificate error for all packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265616/python-easy-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-error-for-all-packages)

But I don't see that any working advice was given or found. Some other advisers asked to install a legacy edition of pip: [pip issue installing almost any library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370583/pip-issue-installing-almost-any-library) But I am unsure how to do it ( as usually installation of pip requires working easy_install ), and it does not help to solve the SSL-broken problem in general.

On the other hand, with the Python Anaconda 1.9.1 distribution shipping Python 2.7.6, `easy_install behave` works fine, on the SAME computer, while other older Python(x,y) 2.7.5.x distributions fail the same way as 2.7.6.0. On another Win7 computer, with Python (x,y) 2.7.6.0, the SSL connection works, i.e. I may process pypi download successfully, e.g. `easy_install behave` works.

So it looks as if something with my Win8.1 is broken. Something with SSL?! A common solution for the last 20 years was "Just reinstall Windows and all its applications" :-(.
I am just unsure to re-install Windows from scratch, as this is so much effort and the success is not guaranteed.

As I need a working installation of QT-for-Python, I would like to use Python(x,y) now, and in general, I would like to have a working non-commercial opensource edition of Python on my computer. I know that on Windows, that the Highlander principle applies: There can be only one!  - So I just may have ONE Python distribution installed, at a time. I did, i.e. I always deinstalled old Python runtimes and/or Python(x,y) or Anaconda.

So any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don´t need instructions how to install "behave" manually ( I succeeded by downloading "parse", "parse-type" and "behave" package source codes, and installed them manually in this order by executing "python setup.py install" each in its source directories, one after the other ). Its just that I don´t want to install future packages with all its dependencies manually, with Python(x,y).

Comment: I am (almost) shure that the problem came up after upgrading from Win8 to Win8.1, as I think that I worked with "behave" on Python(x,y) on the delicate computer before upgrading Windows...