# Installing Tweepy for Python 3 on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I have posted this question before and it seems like no one is able to guide me.
I want to run tweepy on Python 3. I have it working on Python 2 right now.

I followed the steps on this [page](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy)

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

When I go to write

```
python3 setup.py install
```

I get this message of it downloading which obviously means it is not downloading properly.

Why won't it download properly on Python 3?

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing tweepy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to tweepy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to tweepy.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to tweepy.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'tweepy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'tweepy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/examples
copying build/lib/examples/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/examples
copying build/lib/examples/oauth.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/examples
copying build/lib/examples/streaming.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/examples
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
copying build/lib/tweepy/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
copying build/lib/tweepy/api.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
copying build/lib/tweepy/auth.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
copying build/lib/tweepy/binder.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
copying build/lib/tweepy/cache.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
copying build/lib/tweepy/cursor.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
copying build/lib/tweepy/error.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
copying build/lib/tweepy/models.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
copying build/lib/tweepy/parsers.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
copying build/lib/tweepy/streaming.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
copying build/lib/tweepy/utils.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/examples/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/examples/oauth.py to oauth.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/examples/streaming.py to streaming.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/api.py to api.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/auth.py to auth.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/binder.py to binder.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/cache.py to cache.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/cursor.py to cursor.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/error.py to error.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/models.py to models.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/parsers.py to parsers.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/streaming.py to streaming.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/utils.py to utils.cpython-36.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying tweepy.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying tweepy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying tweepy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying tweepy.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying tweepy.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying tweepy.egg-info/zip-safe -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
creating 'dist/tweepy-3.6.0-py3.6.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing tweepy-3.6.0-py3.6.egg
Removing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy-3.6.0-py3.6.egg
Copying tweepy-3.6.0-py3.6.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
tweepy 3.6.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy-3.6.0-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for tweepy==3.6.0
Searching for PySocks>=1.5.7
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/PySocks/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/PySocks/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'PySocks' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for PySocks>=1.5.7
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('PySocks>=1.5.7')
```

Comment: what os is this ?

Comment: os X version 10.11.6 , why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi/28724886

Comment: do I need to install an older python 3 version?

Comment: no you don't, also see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265616/python-easy-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-error-for-all-packages

Comment: i'm confused exactly how to fix it since i don't know if the links you are sending are for window users

Comment: Are you not using pip?

Comment: found this on GitHub.
This might have also been because I recently switched to a new machine and it's still only partially installed :)

For future reference: if you want to use the Python dmg installer, you also have to read Python 3's ReadMe and run the /Applications/Python 3.6/Install Certificates.command bash script to install newer certs.

Thanks for the quick response, @aselle!

Comment: yes I am using pip, i used pip to install tweepy (As shown in the link)                 @harvey_slash what are you referring to? did you mean to post that comment in this thread?

Comment: did you install python from the dmg ? the problem is that the certificates are not installed. Run the command mentioned in my older comment, that installs the certificate

Comment: @harvey_slash whats a dmg? also I was confused with that post because i didn't understand what package I use to put in place of what the person posted. i.e. ( pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org <package_name>)

Answer (score 0):

the solution:

The problem isn't with tweepy it is with the certification in python3 so to fix that look at this link [Python 3 : SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569042/python-3-ssl-certificate-verify-failed)

then to install tweepy type `python3 setup.py install`